# Get quota details in my code side of a GCP Project enabled with Google Maps APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sugarcrm

I am working on a SugarCRM plugin integrated with Google Maps and want to get the quota details of GCP Project in my **code side**. Is there any way to get the quota details if I have checked any of these i.e Directions Api or Places Api

**reference screenshot**

[image: reference screenshot] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find usage for Maps API on "APIs & Services Dashboard":
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/enabled

Here is an example report. In your case it will include JavaScript Maps API:
[image: Google APIs report]

Your account will be billed for usage according to the current price list:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing

Comment: I want all these details in my php code.

Comment: @AsmaMunir I believe it's better to clarify the original question then.